# Node RED + Azure Text to Speech

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, node-red

I am trying to setup an Azure TTS node in my flow but the form fields are a bit confusing... I am wondering if the problem is setup, or flow, or data, but without being able to isolate at least one of them it is quite hard to define where to attack!

this is the scenario:

Fields on NodeRED UI:
- Subscription (Get key)
- Application ID
- User Agent

Fields on Azure Portal:
- Subscription ID
- Access Keys
- Resource Group

Maybe another information I can't figure out where to find???

Any help would help me tremendously!

Comment: and just to add a detail, the debug info is not too much helpful...
`9/1/2017, 1:38:58 PMnode: 69c9e8f2.d075a
msg : string[61]
"Error with text to speech : response status - [object Object]"`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a couple days trying to figure that out I finally understood the relation between the forms fields of this node and the information available in my Azure account.

in Node-RED:

- Subscription (Get key): put here the KEY (you may have 2 of them, but only the first worked for me)
- Application ID: you can create whatever alpha-numeric sequence to uniquely identify your application (numbers and letters only!)
- User Agent: whatever name you want (more intuitive) may work here

That's all!